# Create JSONs from list in directories, created by another list

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to Python and I found myself in a situation where I need to create JSONs out of a list, sort them and store them in directories created out of another list.

Let's say list1 is :

```
- ABC
- DEF
- GHI
- ...
```

And list2 is :

```
 - ABCabc
 - ABCdef
 - DEFabc 
 - GHIabc
 - GHIdef
 - ...
```

I already created the directories from list1 successfully.
But now I need a way to create the values from list2 which names start with the value of list1 as index.json in the directories of list1.

So what I'm looking for is something like :

```
 - ABC
    - index.json
 - DEF
    - index.json
 - GHI
    - index.json
 - ...
```

Where the content of index.json looks like:

```
{
"foobar":[{
        "ABC":"ABCabc"
    },
    {
        "ABC":"ABCdef"
    }]
}
```

My code for the JSONs so far :

```
if [s for s in result if s.startswith(data_extr2)]:
    for i in result:
        try:
            with io.open(os.path.join("index.json"), 'w', encoding="utf-8") as output:
                output.write(unicode(json.dumps(result, ensure_ascii=False)))
        except OSError as exception:
            if exception.errno != errno.EEXIST:
                raise
```

Where `data_extr2` is list1 and `result` is list2.

Cheers in advance

Comment: Can you tell us why what you currently have isn't working?

Comment: When I start the script it obviously processes *something* but in the end it creates an empty index.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand well your code, for me it is broken.

```
# if statement on a list ? It will return True if the list is not empty
# bool([]) == False and bool([1]) == True
# If you want to check if the list is empty, you can use len(results) to return the length of the list.
if [s for s in result if s.startswith(data_extr2)]: 

# startswith take a string in argument, not a list, it should provoke an error
s.startswith(data_extr2)
```

Here a code doing what you want, I hope it will help you to understand, of course this code can be improved, but it is to show you a simple solution.

```
import json

list1 = ['ABC', 'DEF']
list2 = ['ABCabc', 'DEFdef']

output = {'foobar': []}

for a in list1:
    for b in list2:
        if b.startswith(a):
            output['foobar'].append({a: b})
            continue

open('index.json', 'w').write(json.dumps(output))
```

Comment: creates the json like a charm, thanks :)
i needed multiple jsons in multiple directories but i guess i can do the rest by myself, so thanks :)